# Custom initialize function not executing in TestCafe

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, automated-tests, testcafe

I'm creating an initialize function to prepare almost every test I make in TestCafe. But when running the code, it does not get triggered.

I've tried:
- Executing the testdriver without the function: Works
- Wrapping it inside a function without if statements: Works
- Wrapping it inside a function with if statements: Does not work
- Wrapping the if statements inside smaller functions and executing them within a self-executing function inside the init script: Does not work.

```
export async function setupEnvironment(Method: Method, Action?: Action, Frame: number = 43, Viewport: Viewport = 1) {
    await u.selectFrame(Frame);

    if (Method === "") {
        await t.click()} 
    else if (Method === "") {
        await t.click()} 
    else if (Method === "") {
        await t.click()} 
    else if (Method === "") {
        await t.click()} 

    if (Action === "") {
        await t.click();
    } else if (Action === "") {
        await t.click();
    }
}
```

or

```
export async function setupEnvironment(Method: Method, Action?: Action, Frame: number = 43, Viewport: Viewport = 1) {

    async function selectAction(){
        if (Action === "") {
            await t.click();
        } else if (Action === "") {
            await t.click();
        }
    }

    async function selectMethod() {
        if (Method === "") {
            await t.click()} 
        else if (Method === "") {
            await t.click()} 
        else if (Method === "") {
            await t.click()} 
        else if (Method === "") {
            await t.click()} 
    }

    (async function render(){
        selectMethod()
        await u.selectFrame(Frame);
        selectAction()
    }) 
}

test('name test case', async (t) => {
      await i.setupEnvironment(Method., Action.);
});
```

Expected behavior: 
Code executes

Actual behavior:
Nothing happens

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why nothing happens in the first case. I think that no one can give you an answer without the page to test the provided function. In the second case, you forget to call the render function. It's defined inside the setupEnvironment, but never called.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've got it to work, and the reason it did not work was there was no action following.. My best guess is that TestCafe scan's the test case on forehand and if no test driver is called, the test will pass automatically without getting inside the external function.

Comment: It's not quite correct. The TestCafe test function (the second argument of `test`) is asynchronous. 
It means that if you await some function execution, the test will wait until this function finishes. 
And the use of the [TestCafe test controller](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/test-code-structure.html#test-controller) isn't necessary for this behavior.
I updated Artem's answer to show possible options of the `setupEnvironment` function implementation.